# Binding button in GridViewColumn not work

Tags: c#, xaml, button, mvvm, binding

I have problem.
I want a button to remove user. However, nothing happens when I click button. The problem occurs because the button is in:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
        <Button Margin="0" CommandParameter="UserID" Command="{Binding RemoveUserButton}">Usuń</Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

The button works when it is elsewhere. However, I want to put it here to get the id immediately. 
How to fix it?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ManagementProjectSystem.Admin"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ManagementProjectSystem"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Admin" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ListViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Users">
                <Grid Background="RosyBrown">

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="396*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="396*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                              .....................
                                <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" Header="DateCreateAccount"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateCreateAccount}" Width="115"/>

                                <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" Header="Usuń" Width="40">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate >
                                            <Button Margin="0" CommandParameter="UserID" Command="{Binding RemoveUserButton}">Usuń</Button>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

XAML.cs:

```
public partial class Admin : Window
{
    public Admin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AdminViewModel vm = new AdminViewModel();
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```cs
public ICommand RemoveUserButton { get; set; }
public AdminViewModel()
{
    RemoveUserButton = new DelegateCommand<object>(RemoveUser);
}

private void RemoveUser(object ID)
{
    int val = Convert.ToInt32(ID);
    User user = dbContext.User.Find(val);
    dbContext.User.Remove(user);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    _Users.Remove(user);
}
```

The parameter is of type object because int showed errors. But id is stored in the database as int.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @ShahidManzoorBhat I have no error. A table with three users (downloaded from the database) is displayed. After clicking the button, the method is not called.

Comment: You are trying to remove the user does this method ever get called?

Comment: @ShahidManzoorBhat This method works when it creates a button somewhere outside of ListView. The problem is that it's on the list. As if it wasn't visible then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `DataContext` for your `GridView` will be of type `User`. But you're trying to bind to `ICommand` present in your `ViewModel`. You can try `RelativeSource`. Like,

```xml
<Button Content="Usuń"
        CommandParameter="{Binding UserID}" 
        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.RemoveUserButton, 
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView, 
                                               Mode=FindAncestor}" />
```